# Understanding proof of existence of cycle decomposition for $\sigma\in S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions, symmetric-groups

The following is what I took from Dummit and foote on page 115. I understood everything except why we can deduce for each $\sigma\in S_n$ there exists a cycle decomposition from the bijection?
is it because if we take $\sigma(x)\in \mathscr{O}$ then there exists $\tau\in G=\langle\sigma\rangle$
such that $\tau(x)=\sigma(x)$ but then $\tau=\sigma^{k}$ for some $0\leq k\leq d-1$. Which is just a iterate of $\sigma$.

> Let $\sigma\in S_n$ and set $G=\langle\sigma\rangle$ then $G$ acting on $A= \{1,\ldots,n\}$ partitions $A$ into unique disjoint sets of orbits. Let $\mathscr{O}$ be one of those orbits and let $x\in \mathscr{O}$ we can define a bijection from $\mathscr{O}$ to $G/G_x$ where $G_x$ is the stablizer of $x$ in $G$. $$\sigma^i x\mapsto \sigma^i G_x$$
> Because $G$ is cyclic, $G_x$ normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/G_x$ is cyclic of order $d$, where $d$ is the smallest positive integer $\sigma^d\in G_x$
> And $d=|G:G_x|=|\mathscr{O}|$. Thus the distinct cosets of $G_x$ are $$G_x,\sigma G_x,\cdots, \sigma^{d-1}G_x$$
> and the distinct element of $\mathscr{O}$ are $$x,\sigma(x),\cdots , \sigma^{d-1}(x)$$
> On an orbit of size $d$, $\sigma$ acts as $d$-cycle. This proves the existence of a cycle decomposition for each $\sigma\in S_n$

Thanks for explaining!

Comment: I recommend taking a specific permutation and running through this proof with that specific permutation, calculating everything as you go. That should give you a lot of insight. Here's a permutation with $n=10$ that should be illuminating: $(1)(2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)(7\ 8\ 9\ 10)$. (I know it's obvious that that one has a cycle deomposition, but I still think it will be valuable to go understand how the proof works for that specific example.)